# How to view HEIC format pictures in Explorer and the Photos app on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, photos

How can I view my HEIC (High Efficiency Image File Format) pictures in Explorer and the Photos app in Windows 10 Explorer?

Explorer shows blank icons instead of the previews.
The Photos app gives this message : "We can't open this file".

Even IrfanView (popular Image Viewer) with the necessary plugins installed, would load the files but display only a blank screen.

Microsoft's "HEIF Image Extensions" app in the Microsoft Store (free), which was recommended on various forums, did not solve the issues on my machine.

I'm on Windows 10 V1909, 2020-06 Cumulative Update (KB4567512, Build 18363.904).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much research, Microsoft offers another app in the Microsoft Store called "[HEVC Video Extensions](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/hevc-video-extensions/9NMZLZ57R3T7)".

That second extension has solved the problem. Don't be fooled by the "Video" part in the name. Once installed : Explorer shows previews for HEIC pictures, the Photos app loads them, and even IrfanView now loads them properly.

Sad part : that extension is not free, Microsoft is asking you to pay 0.99 USD for it.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me immediately after installing!  99 cents sucks, should be a free part of windows but whatever at this point after searching/trying various things.

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: The HEIC Video Extension works but is terribly slow. Sorting a large number of HEIC images is almost impossible.

Comment: As I commented in the other answer; Yesterday (03/11/2022) I found this link https://dries.metrico.be/2021/01/21/no-longer-free-windows-10-hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/ which said to put this in my browser (which is firefox): `ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq`. When I did so, it prompted me to log into my micros0ft account, which I (reluctantly) logged in to. The microsoft store started, and above the "redeem code" button was an 'Install' button which worked. Free.

Comment: @johnvkumpf - thank you that worked perfectly

Comment: @johnvkumpf I was excited to see this possible solution, however it says 'this app will not run on this device'. I'm running Windows10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: @kalamlka kid , this comment pertains to another answer, the one by questionto42 below.

Answer (score 5):

### 202306

At first, follow the 202203 header. If you get to the Microsoft Store App and see a background style "Install" button, which looks as if it was deactivated:

[image]

You might be lucky and still get it done. A comment below says:

> I had to do it twice. The first time the 'Install' link wasn't there or I didnt see it. It's weirdly styled to look like it's in the background so maybe my brain's visual parser missed it. It was ABOVE the "Redeem Code". I am on w10pro 21H2 so a little behind.

This did not work for me:

- browsers: Chrome, Edge
- Edition   Windows 10 Education
- Version   22H2
- 19045.3086
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

But you should give it a try.

### 202203

A link without costs is back. You need to login in the Microsoft Store, that is all. Paste this in your browser and click on install:

- ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq
- Install the "HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer". Thanks go to a helpful comment below.
- If you still do not see the pictures, install HEIF extension at [HEIF extension microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_159229&tduid=%28ir__2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6eb1j6idbk00%29%287593%29%28159229%29%28%29%28UUwpUdUnU56887YYwYwnb2hi4dthixs6zdvmnvwi5ldnntw6ltdn5wq%29&irclickid=_2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6eb1j6idbk00&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab).

### 202110:

This is a workaround, it does not answer the question: Just download the free HEIC Image Viewer from the Microsoft Store. Then you can open them or drag and drop them there.

[image]

---

**EDITED ANSWER: the whole "old answer" (which the upvote was for) is outdated, the free link is not free anymore, thus the other answer is already saying what is needed.**

### Older answer:

Download [Copytrans HEIC](https://www.copytrans.net/copytransheic/), shift-right-click a HEIC picture and choose "Open with", then choose "Windows Foto Viewer" instead of the standard "Photos" app.

The new answer that may serve as a free workaround to avoid the 0.99 € Microsoft Store link does not fully answer the question, as it:

- does not show the thumbnails in Windows Explorer, although this is claimed by the website (and still seems to take the time as if it loaded the thumbnails, with the bad effect that you need to wait for the Explorer to load all not-shown "thumbnails" and you cannot leave the view at that moment) and
- only shows the pictures in "Windows Foto Viewer" instead of the standard "Photos" app.

One last workaround which is even further away from answering the question  is to load up the pictures to "Google Photos" and not to choose "original quality", but "very good quality" (which is a compressed jpg format), and download them back from whatever album you assign them to.

**Or in other words: Better spend the 0,99 ;).**

### Old answer (outdated, free link not free anymore, other answer already covers this):

***You need two drivers***, which is not well documented when you just use some random search engine results or the microsoft store.

This link helps out: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-heic-and-hevc-files-windows-10s-photos-app.

The following steps are borrowed from this guide, I recommend going there instead. Stack sites simply ask you to post an extract as the link can break.

During installation from microsoft store, you might enter your microsoft account (which might be good if you want to document your installations). I have installed both drivers without registering.

It is not important which of the two installations comes first. The guide suggests the following order, I could also do it the other way round as well:

- Install HEVC for free **(no need to pay 0.99 $)**, in contrast to the other answer! [HEVC free microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9n4wgh0z6vhq?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_159229&tduid=%28ir__2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6et1j6idbk00%29%287593%29%28159229%29%28%29%28UUwpUdUnU56887YYwYwnb2hi4dthixs6zdvmnvwi5ldnntw6ltdn5wq%29&irclickid=_2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6et1j6idbk00&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)
- Install HEIF extension at [HEIF extension microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_159229&tduid=%28ir__2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6eb1j6idbk00%29%287593%29%28159229%29%28%29%28UUwpUdUnU56887YYwYwnb2hi4dthixs6zdvmnvwi5ldnntw6ltdn5wq%29&irclickid=_2xsqogvpl9kftxebkk0sohz3zv2xih6eb1j6idbk00&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab).

####

Summing up the search experience:

You find scattered information when you search just for HEIC, and the Microsoft Store does not tell you that you also need the HEVC driver, I have not seen this on the download page of the HEIC driver or elsewhere. The HEVC is a video driver! This is weird because I remember that I struggled with this HEIC-driver-in-Fotos question already at the beginning of 2019. I know that back then, I found out about this "2-drivers-trick" only after half an hour. I am certainly not the only one if I have the exact same issue again after half a year.

My search steps in detail for anyone interested - perhaps microsoft store should read this ;):

- If you want to open a HEIC-file, and you search for it with "open heic windows 10", you do not expect to have to install HEVC as well to make HEIC work. In the end, the whole solution was offered at the very first position of the search results, searching for "open heic windows 10" or "how to show heic in fotos windows", but I did not click on it.
- Instead, I scrolled further down to the microsoft links (which every normal user should probably do as well), and strange enough, microsoft just offers the free-heic-viewer as an answer [free-heic-viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/free-heic-viewer/9n0sq6tb52vx), which is probably not the driver for HEIC to be seen in "Fotos", but an additional app, that is why I did not install it.
- The HEIC viewer search result info box had the note "If you want to convert HEIC files to other format, you could download "HEIC Image Converter S" or "HEIC Image Viewer - Support Converter". But that again is a misleading step, because we do not want to convert HEIC to jpg. Of course you can download that converter as well, it works and makes jpg out of your HEIC. It is not recommended, though: jpg is bigger than HEIC since space is used less efficiently, do this only if you need to work on it or have a common format at hand. Converting is not the aim of the question. I did not download the HEIC converter because I had this converter on my other PC from an installation half a year ago and I knew that this converter did not help out with the Fotos app.
- Then I went on searching for "HEIC microsoft store" which gave me only one of the two drivers, showing pictures in Fotos still not working.
- Only then I clicked on the first hit of the search results, getting the right guide that hints at HEVC as well.

Comment: The link you provided points to "HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer"; I guess that version originates from an OEM, and might as well be exactly the same as the 99 cents paid one from MS. The link is in the "Deutschland - Deutsch" locale; for anyone reading this, the english version is here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9n4wgh0z6vhq

However, as of 2020-11-25, the page mentions : "HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer is currently not available." Maybe MS discovered it and pulled it because that one was free.

Comment: @mach128x that is sad. Yes, they seem to have withdrawn the offer, hopefully just for some time, but likely forever. Thank you for commenting on this.

Comment: Can confirm that, as you write, it does not show the thumbnails in Windows Explorer

Comment: You keep editing your original answer by adding fundamentally different content (latest in date : the 12/10/2021 update about the HEIC Image Viewer). StackExchange etiquette says that when someone has a "new" answer (i.e. an answer that is in essence different than the ones the person has previously posted), it should be posted as a separate answer.
Otherwise your submission becomes a big confusing mess.

Comment: Besides, 'HEIC Image Viewer' doesn't solve the issues at hand, clearly stated in the question : "How to view HEIC format pictures in **Explorer** and **the Photos app** on Windows 10"

Comment: @mach128x I remember that I could do that when I had HEVC and HEIF extension which now costs 0.99 and which is what the other answer is for. I have only answered in addition since I had seen a free link at that time (now outdated). Later, I tried to find something free again and show only some workarounds here. It is likely better to spend the 0.99 $ and ignore this answer, this answer is more for those who want to check just a few pictures lying around, it does not answer the question *anymore*.

Comment: Today (03/11/2022) I found this link https://dries.metrico.be/2021/01/21/no-longer-free-windows-10-hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/ which said to put this in my browser (which is firefox): `ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq`. When I did so, it prompted me to log into my micros0ft account, which I (reluctantly) did. Above the "redeem code" was an 'Install' button which worked. Free.

Comment: @johnvkumpf Great news, since logging in was needed before anyway, but now you can again avoid registering a payment there. That was brave of you, one took the risk for all.

Comment: 20230530: The costless link does not work on Windows 10 anymore, at least on another laptop. The store's red banner says roughly: "This app is not supported by your device".

Comment: It worked for me today, 06/30/2023 (happy 4th) but I confess I had to do it twice. The first time the 'Install' link wasn't there or I didnt see it. It's weirdly styled to look like it's in the background so maybe my brain's visual parser missed it. It was ABOVE the "Redeem Code". I am on w10pro 21H2 so a little behind.

Comment: @johnvkumpf Thus, was it in the Microsoft Store App that or did you click to install it from within a browser only, perhaps from cache? Since I still cannot install it, it says "This app is not supported by your device". And I do not know how to stay inside the browser, the link will always open the MS Store App, and then, the "Install" button is styled like it's in the background, sort of deactivated. I will still add your advice to the answer.

Comment: @questionto42 yes, started in browser, redirected to app. Both times.

Comment: @johnvkumpf good. shortly: which browser? Else, we can guess that it is just the version 21H2 that can do it, since I have 22H2, and it does not work there. As you say it.

Comment: @questionto42 Firefox version approximately 106.

Answer (score -1):

Free solution with imagemagick & small batch file you can drag'n'drop HEIC files on to convert to JPG:

1. Download [ImageMagick Portable (ImageMagick-7.1.0-portable-Q16-x64.zip)](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
2. Extract `magick.exe` from zip file
3. Open notepad, copy & paste below code into it, save as `Heic-iPhoneConvert-DropFilesOn.bat`

```
REM %~dp0 is the location of THIS batch file (%0=file path including the filename [%~nx0 only filename], dp tells it to cut that out [DrivePath only], quotes help if there is spaces in the path). To see more info enter this FOR /?
REM %~dpn1 means full file path excluding file extension of the DROPPED USER FILE: %1 user file full path with extension, ~dp before 1 says DrivePath, n means fileName without extension. Ex: C:\Folder\Filename. So save converted file as same name & location as original file
REM magick.exe is our conversion tool that needs to be in same directory as this batch script. we have to double percentage-symbol on quality so batch doesn't think its a variable as those start with percentage-symbol

"%~dp0magick.exe" %InputFile% -quality 95%% "%~dpn1.jpg"
```

Comment: This answer does not address the question. The question is not about converting files, but enabling Windows to parse them natively. Of course Windows Explorer can display any file after they've been converted to a basic file format, but that is not the point.

Comment: Apart from being an answer to the question or not: is it possible to convert a whole folder of pictures with this tool? Since I remember vaguely (not sure, though) that the also free HEIC Image Viewer from the Microsoft Store does not offer you this. Perhaps the tool of your answer has it?