# Cache Image Thumbnails in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, images, windows-11-v22h2

I started using HEIC images to save storage space. I'm really happy with the format as the quality is good and the compression is great. However, one thing I'm struggling with is how long the thumbnails take to load when I open a folder with HEIC images.

I can understand if it takes a while to load the first time, but each time I open a folder, HEIC folders reload entirely to show thumbnails:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Windows 11 to save HEIC thumbnails in cache so after loading them once, I can quickly re-open the folder to see the contents?

The images I'm trying to view are on my hard drive, thus the expectation is they should load quickly.

According to my Windows settings, image thumbnails should be cached, but it's not working:

[image]

### PC Specs

- Device: HP Envy 17 2023
- Processor: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1355U, 1.70 GHz
- RAM: 32.0 GB
- OS:   Windows 11 Pro 22H2
- Storage: 1TB SSD

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Windows load .heic thumbnails faster?](https://superuser.com/questions/1806936/how-can-windows-load-heic-thumbnails-faster)

Comment: I tried the suggestion and installed WinThumbsPreloader. When I run it, nothing happens. Is it compatible with Windows 11?

Comment: I had a similar experience. I had downloaded the standalone executable (suitable to run in command line). Instead, download and run the setup executable. This will create folder context menu entries. In Windows explorer, right click on a folder, choose "Show more options" then "WinThumbsPreloader/Preload Thumbnails". Not sure if this solves the underlying problem but I was able to get the preloader to run.

Comment: @Stanwood What's the URL where you downloaded the setup executable?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and earlier Windows 11 versions, the method below of changing relevant Registry key values allowed to prevent Windows from deleting thumbnail cache at each reboot. It might still work for your Windows version. However, in Windows 11 Pro 23H2 it no longer works, likely due to ongoing changes to File Explorer. It must be reported to Microsoft File Explorer team as a bug.

The thumbnail cache for each user is stored as .db files in the hidden folder:

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
(C:\Users{user-name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer)

Open Regedit and change value of Autorun Dword from 3 to 0 in the keys below:

(32-bit and 64-bit)
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Thumbnail Cache

(64-bit only)
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Thumbnail Cache

You can also increase thumbnail cache size by opening the Registry key in Regedit

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

then creating, if doesn't exist, a new String Value named **Max Cached Icons**, and setting its Value Data to 4096 or higher.