# iCloud photos on Windows 11 not downloading or rendering

Tags: windows-11, photos, icloud

I just built a new Windows 11 PC, and one of the things I wanted to use it for was to have an offline copy of all of my iCloud photos (total library size is about 1TB across 200k files) and be able to view them in the Windows Photos app.

So I installed iCloud for Windows, set it to sync my photo library, enabled the "Always keep on this device" option on the "iCloud Photos" folder, left it to do it's thing for a week or so, and now iCloud claims to have synced everything.

The first issue is that if I open the properties of my iCloud Photos folder, Windows reports the size on disk as only 9 MB. Is this because iCloud actually hasn't downloaded anything, or is Windows being clever here and not including the size of files that are also stored in the cloud (similar to what Mac OS handles purgeable space)? Is there any way that I can see what files have actually been downloaded?

The second issue is in the Windows Photos app. The iCloud Photos folder is shown there, but when I open it, no thumbnails are available, all of the pictures are just gray frames. Double-clicking to open one just gives a spinner animation. Shouldn't the Photos app at least generate thumbnails for all photos regardless of whether they have been downloaded? Most of the photos are JPG.

I'm not sure if I've configured something wrong or if I'm just expecting too much of the software with this size of library?

Comment: I have found due to the file format iOS uses you will have to move the files out of your iCloud folder for thumbnails to work. You also need to install a HEIF image extension from the Windows Store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view HEIC format pictures in Explorer and the Photos app on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1570247/how-to-view-heic-format-pictures-in-explorer-and-the-photos-app-on-windows-10)

Comment: Despite the answers age I can confirm it’s still applicable to Windows 11. Yes; the size of your iCloud folder is an effort to safe space.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but most of the images are JPG that were taken from a digital camera, so I don't think this is an explanation for it. All thumbnails are missing, not just for photos taken from my iphone.